# python: trouble printing short utf-encoded strings

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

(The following is using Python 2.6.1)

I have 2 strings:

```
>>> a = u'\u05e8\u05db\u05e1'
>>> b = u'\u05e8\u05db\u05e1 \u05d4\u05d9\u05d0 \u05de\u05d0\u05d9\u05e8\u05d4 \u05d1\u05e4\u05e0\u05e1'
```

I encode them:

```
>>> ua = a.encode('utf-8')
>>> ub = b.encode('utf-8')
>>> ua
'\xd7\xa8\xd7\x9b\xd7\xa1'
>>> ub
'\xd7\xa8\xd7\x9b\xd7\xa1 \xd7\x94\xd7\x99\xd7\x90 \xd7\x9e\xd7\x90\xd7\x99\xd7\xa8\xd7\x94 \xd7\x91\xd7\xa4\xd7\xa0\xd7\xa1'
```

and try to print:

```
>>> print ua
×¨×›×¡
>>> print ub
רכס היא מאירה בפנס
```

Why does `ub` print in Hebrew characters while `ua` doesn't?  `ua` is just the first few characters of `ub`, so it seems as though string length is somehow the problem, which is weird.

(For the record, this came up trying to parse a webpage with BeautifulSoup -- I couldn't tell why some paragraphs came out readably while others didn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be something with your terminal settings; `ua` prints three Hebrew characters on my terminal (Terminal.app on OS X), exactly the rightmost three characters of `ub`. (Since Hebrew is a right-to-left script, the rightmost three characters are the first three).

For the record, I've tried it with Python 2.6.1.

Comment: Huh, you're right!  Still weird, but at least now I can keep working.  :)


Thank you!


(for anyone coming upon this question later, I was using IDLE 2.6.1)